# Does this statement logically follow from Euclid's theorem?

Tags: logic

Assume that Euclid's theorem is "*For every relatively prime positive integers $m$ and $n$, there exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $am + bn = 1.$*"

Writing this with logical notation, if $R$ is the predicate that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and $C$ is the predicate that $m$, $n$, $a$ and $b$ satisfy the equation $am + bn = 1$, we would get

$\forall m,n (R(m,n)\implies \exists(a,b)C(m,n,a,b))$

Now, consider the statement "*There exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\times15 + b\times7 = 1.$*" Does it directly follow from Euclid's theorem? And how would we write this statement with logical notation?

Comment: $\exists a,b (15a+7b=1)$

Comment: The proof is: (i) show that $15$ and $7$ are relative prime, i.e. that $R(15,7)$ holds. Then (ii) use them to instantiate the formula to get $R(15,7) \to ∃a,bC(15,7,a,b)$. Finally (iii) conclude by Modus Ponens.

Comment: I was thinking that the statment can directly be transalted to $\exists a,bC(a,b,15,7)$. Also, does your proof mean that the statement directly follows from Euiclid's theorem?

Comment: It follows if $15$ and $7$ are relatively prime.  Which they are.  But one may need to verify that that they are.  And in logical notation just write $\exists(a,b)C(15,7,a,b)$.    The statement doesn't make any condition if $7,15$ are relatively prime nor make any claim that they are.  So translating the statement "there exist integers $a$ and $b$ so that $x\times 15+b\times 7 =1" is just "$\exists(a,b)C(15,7,a,b)$" but the *proof* would require more.

Comment: "I was thinking that the statment can directly be transalted to ∃a,bC(a,b,15,7)"  Almost. YOu have the symbols in the wrong positions.  "Also, does your proof mean that the statement directly follows from Euiclid's theorem?" I'm not sure what you mean by "directly". You need to know somehow that $7$ and $15$ *are* relatively prime.  But once you know that it follows from the theorem.  if the statement is true for all pairs of relatively prime integers, it must be true for $7$ and $15$ because $7$ and $15$ are relatively prime.  Not sure exactly what the issue is or what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Oops, I had mixed up the places, and now get the notation part. As for whether it directly follows from the theorem, I mean if the statement can logically be derived from the theorem. The part I'm stuck at is that the statement doesn't cointain the predicate R. Can we add R to the statement while making sure that the new statement would be equivalent to the originial one? I mean, it is trivial to prove that 7 and 15 are relatively prime, but how can we incorporate that into the statement?